# Is there any better algorithm to find shortest path in a directed graph than Dijkstra Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I know BFS can only be used to find the shortest path in the case of undirected graphs with no weights.  So , I was wondering , is there any better algorithm than Dijkstra algorithm to find shortest path in the case of directed graphs with unweighted edges .

I tried searching online for the answer and found several articles but none of them mentioned it explicitly . So , I am hoping if any one can clarify it .

Comment: Why can you not use BFS with a directed, unweighted graph?

Comment: @beaker I know BFS can be used with directed and unweighted graph . But I do not know whether it can be used to find the shortest path in the case of directed and unweighted graph .

Comment: Yes, it can. Whether or not the graph is directed or not doesn't matter. You just need to know that it's unweighted. For Dijkstra btw you must not have negative weights. Otherwise Dijkstra is quite fast as well with a runtime of `O((|E|+|V|) log |V|)
`. That is only a factor of `log |V|` slower than BFS with `O(|E|+|V|)`

Comment: @Mushroomator So , BFS will give correct shortest path order in the case of directed and unweighted graph . That's what you mean , right ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: You can use various Algorithms. It mainly depends on your needs. You can use Bellman-Ford Algorithm, Floyd-Warshall Algorithm etc.